# Google Sheets Script that Changes Background Color of Range to match the Hex Value in a Separate List

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, colors, background-color

I have [a range (S3:Z4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qq4w.png) in a sheet called SUMMARY that I'd like to be able to set the background color of based on a hex value in a different tab (REFERENCE) of the sheet. Cell W3 of SUMMARY contains the name of a college.

In the REFERENCE tab, there is a column (Column AB) of a list of colleges. In the adjacent column AC, there are a list of Hex values that corresponds to the team color of that school.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFP6B.png)

What I want to happen is that OnEdit if I change the school name in cell W3 of SUMMARY, that all of the range S3:Z4 of summary change to match the hex value found that corresponds with that school in the REFERENCE tab.

I've seen other questions related to this topic but none that really apply to my situation. I'm just getting my feet wet with Google Sheets scripts, so that said anyone have a means to make this happen? I imagine it could be useful for other people even if their ranges are different by just replacing certain things in the script.

Comment: A couple of screenshots wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Added a couple.

Answer (score 1):

About the same as Cooper's:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart != 3 || e.range.columnStart != 23) return;
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'SUMMARY') return;
  
  var ss = e.source;
  var ref_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('REFERENCE');
  var data = ref_sheet.getRange('A1:B3').getValues();
  var colors = {};
  data.forEach(c => colors[c[0]] = c[1]);

  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SUMMARY');
  var college = e.value;
  dest_sheet.getRange('S3:Z4').setBackground(colors[college]); 
}
```

[Here is my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/166VhV4NGuFe7QQfVUKL8yCsiCh955Fm9RTD_HQb5S50/edit?usp=sharing) to test.

**Update**

Here is the updated version that recolors backgrounds and fonts (based on column AD):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart != 3 || e.range.columnStart != 23) return;
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'SUMMARY') return;
  
  var ss = e.source;
  var ref_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('REFERENCE');
  var data = ref_sheet.getRange('AB2:AD13').getValues();
  var dest_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SUMMARY');
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange('S3:Z4');
  var college = e.value;

  // set backgrounds
  var backgrounds = {};
  data.forEach(c => backgrounds[c[0]] = c[1]);
  dest_range.setBackground(backgrounds[college]);

  // set font colors
  var font_colors = {};
  data.forEach(c => font_colors[c[0]] = c[2]);
  recolor_text(dest_range, font_colors[college]);
}

function recolor_text(range, color) {
  var style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor(color).build();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var rich_values = [];
  for (let row in values) {
    var rich_row = [];
    for (let value of values[row]) {
      var rich_value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(value).setTextStyle(style).build();
      rich_row.push(rich_value);
    }
    rich_values.push(rich_row);
  }
  range.setRichTextValues(rich_values);
}
```

My test spreadsheet is behind the same link.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. If I wanted to add a column with the colleges' secondary colors in column AD on the REFERENCE tab, would it be easy to add that the FontColor of cells S3:Z4 on the SUMMARY tab change to match that hex code?

Comment: To recolor fonts is a much trickier task (it needs to use RichTextValues). I've added the updated version of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "SUMMARY" && e.range.columnStart == 23 && e.range.rowStart == 3) {
    const rsh = e.source.getSheetByName("REFERENCE");
    const rshsr = 2;//reference sheet data start row
    const bgA = rsh.getRange(rshsr, 28, rsh.getLastRow() - rshsr + 1, 2).getValues();
    const row = bgA.find(r => r[0] == e.value)
    sh.getRange("S3:Z4").setBackground(row[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting this - TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined.

What should I check to make sure it's set up correctly? I did notice I believe the columnStart for the SUMMARY tab should be 19 (Column S), right?

Comment: You cannot run this from the script editor.  Save it and go to the sheet and select a school.

Comment: It runs.  I've tested it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help! For my own understanding, what is the 23 referencing in the 3rd line? 23 actually is the correct value so I'm confused because I assumed it would be referencing column S (19).